# Convertto-html multiple columns

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have a list of computer names, I would like to convert this list to HTML with an output of 4 columns. When I pipe my `$Computerlist | format-wide -column 4` in my console I get nicely formatted output in 4 columns.

But when I try to convert it to HTML: `$Computerlist | format-wide -column 4 | Convertto-html` it just return an empty page.

And without formatting `$Computerlist | Convertto-html` I get my list of computer names but in one column.

Comment: You want the list to take up 4 columns or you just want an extra 4 columns of empty values?

Comment: Can you tell us what $ComputerList actually is? An example of the object or its type?

Comment: Hello guys thanks for quick replay. @Bill, the `$computerlist` contains all computers from my AD `Get-Adcomputer -filter *`, there are more than 5k computers accounts.@Matt, i just need to split my output of 5k computers object in 4 column instead of one

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on trying to remove the header that is created that you will most likely not want but here is the manipulation of the `Format-Wide` output that creates an object to satisfy the needs of `ConvertTo-HTML`

```
$columns = 5
$formatWideOutput = (Get-Process | Format-Wide -Column $columns | Out-String) -split "`r`n"
$formatWideOutput | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{
    $rowData = ([string]$_).Trim() -split '\s{2,}'
    $row = @{}
    For($rowIndex = 0;$rowIndex -lt $columns;$rowIndex++){
        $row.Add("Column$($rowIndex)",$rowData[$rowIndex])
    }
    [pscustomobject]$row
} | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content c:\temp\test.html
```

The above example uses `Get-Process` for input but can be changed to `$Computerlist` once you have tested.

The output of `Format-Wide` is converted to a newline delimited string. Then each `row` is split on a group of white space to create the 5 items. Make a `[pscustomobject]` from those pieces.